# Is it possible to pass electric current through magnet without affecting it?

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose we have a row of $5$ electromagnets, with a copper wire connecting them. Is it possible to create magnetic field in the $4^{th}$ magnet without affecting the $1^{st}$,$2^{nd}$,$3^{rd}$ and $5^{th}$ magnet by passing electric current through the copper wire. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the cores are connected in sequence through a single copper wire, the desired effect will not be possible to create with standard electromagnets.  By Lenz' law and the constitutional electromagnetic equations, a current will induce a field around the magnet. The most simplest of ways is to use a copper wire for each magnet individually, but this will break the serial structure that you propose.